# Why use decltype on a template argument?

Tags: c++, templates, types, decltype

In https://github.com/stlab/libraries/blob/main/stlab/concurrency/main_executor.hpp, I read

```
struct main_executor_type {
    using result_type = void;

    template <typename F>
    void operator()(F f) const {
        using f_t = decltype(f);

        dispatch_async_f(dispatch_get_main_queue(), new f_t(std::move(f)), [](void* f_) {
            auto f = static_cast<f_t*>(f_);
            (*f)();
            delete f;
        });
    }
};
```

What is the point of the `decltype(f)`, why no simply use `F`?

Comment: FWIW, this may be interesting for your to read: http://thbecker.net/articles/auto_and_decltype/section_01.html

Comment: Very nice read, it clarified a lot of tings, thank you!

Answer (score 9):

It depends, since there're some cases leading to different effect between `F` and `decltype(f)`.

For example, `F` could be specified explicitly as array or function type, and the type of function parameter will be adjusted to pointer. Then `F` and `decltype(f)` give different result.

```
template <typename F> // suppose F is specified as array of T or function type F
void operator()(F f) const {
    using f_t = decltype(f); // f_t will be pointer to T or pointer to F
    ...
}
```

Comment: So why not `std::decay`?

Comment: @iBug `std::decay` removes cv-qualifiers then leads to another different effect.

Answer (score 3):

I cannot see any useful scenario for this particular code example (please correct me if I'm wrong), but it would look differently if the parameter would have been declared as cv-qualified, e.g. `const F f`. Then, `using f_t = decltype(f);` would evaluate to `const F`, while `using f_t = F;` would remove cv qualifiers and evaluate to `F`.

Consider the following minimalistic example for better understanding:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
void foo(const T t) {
    using X = decltype(t);
    static_assert(std::is_const_v<X>); // will fail if using X = T;
}

int main() {
    const int a = 123;
    foo(a); // T will be deduced to int, i.e. cv qualifiers are removed
}
```